# How do I place labels within opaque text boxes at group centroids in ordiellipse?

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to place labels within opaque text boxes at my group centroids in `vegan::ordiellipse()`.

Code below yields plot below. Note that centroid labels default to plain text with no opaque text box.

```
library(vegan)

ordiplot(jac_pcoa, main = Trt) 
ordiellipse(jac_pcoa, 
        draw = "polygon",
        kind = "se",
        groups = pcoa_grps, 
        col = col_vect,
        lwd = 2)
ordiellipse(jac_pcoa, groups = pcoa_grps, 
        kind = "ehull", 
        col = col_vect,
        lwd = 2,
        label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Function `vegan::ordispider()`, however, formats the labels as I want.

```
ordiplot(jac_pcoa, main = i) 
ordispider(jac_pcoa, groups = pcoa_grps, 
            col = col_vect,
            lwd = 2,
            label = TRUE)
```

[image]

How can I achieve labels like those generated by `ordispider()` when using `ordiellipse()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to do this directly, but you can trick the function to do what you want: `ordiellipse` will draw labels on opaque labels with `draw = "polygon"`. Setting `col=NULL` or omitting the `col` argument will only draw non-filled ellipses, and the colour of the border line can be set with argument `border`.